# ¿Por que me sale este error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function requiere_once()

Tags: php

el error completo es este :

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\mvc\modelo\datos_modelo.php on line 25
> No te has logeado ;

> Notice: Undefined variable: array_datos in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\mvc\vista\vista.php on line 13

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\mvc\vista\vista.php on line 13

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'modelo/datos_modelo' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\mvc\controlador\datos_controlador.php on line 2

Estoy intentando hacer la estructura básica para un mvc en php que tenga un login y una pestaña de registro, he rescrito el código 4 veces y cuando lanzo el index me sale este error, creo que el error esta en el archivo datos_controlador. Aquí adjunto su código:
Edición, modifique el código ahora no se muy bien porque falla, lo malo es que stack over flow no me deja subir todo el código.

```
<?php
require_once ("modelo/datos_modelo.php");

$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre'])?$_POST['nombre']:'';
$contraseña = isset($_POST['contraseña'])?$_POST['contraseña']:'';

$dato = new Datos_modelo();//llamamos al constructor
if ($dato->get_login($nombre,$contraseña)){
$array_datos = $dato->get_datos();
}
require_once("vista/vista.php");
?>
```

Comment: El require está mal hecho... el archivo debe ser .php y no se lo has puesto. `require_once('modelo/datos_modelo.php')`

Comment: Por qué es **require** más lo que te dice el compañero

Comment: Porque PHP no habla spanglish, `requiere_once` no existe, es `require_once`. :-)

Comment: No me fije que el error decía requiere XDDDD que cieeego fuí !!

Comment: Lee los 4 mensajes al inicio de la pregunta. Ahí te describe muy bien los errores. El código no está fallando solamente aquí, sino también en `datos_modelo.php`, en `vista.php` y en `datos_controlador.php` Son todos errores básicos, de novatos, ya tratados en Stackoverflow, si depuras el código comprendiendo lo que haces en cada uno de esos archivos resolverás el problema y te reubicarás en tu propio código, entendiéndolo mejor. Eso que ahora parece perder el tiempo no lo es, estás en un buen punto ahora para entender y empezar a dominar tu código. No sigas adelante sin entender lo que haces.

Comment: Si ya los modifique ya me funciona bien gracias igualmente

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba a hacerlo así: `require_once 'datos_modelo.php';`

Comment: Eso me ha ayudado en parte pero ahora me salen otros fallos XD

Comment: Dime, ¿qué te errores te salen?

Comment: Ya lo consegui resolver, aun asi me ayudo esto gracias

Comment: Es con mucho gusto amigo